# Flutter Fastlane Gitlab Build

Tags: android, flutter, gitlab, continuous-integration, fastlane

I am new to Fastlane and want to build my apk through the Fastlane and Gitlab. I have been getting this error whenever I run the Fastlane command:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/builds/sw/pro/pro_app_flutter/android/app/build.gradle' line: 30
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read script '/Users/your-user/Library/Android/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

But I am unable to figure this out, what does this mean because flutter.gradle does exist on the path!

Moreover the build from Android Studio is successfully generated!
Thanks in advance

P.S my fast file:

```
default_platform(:android)
platform :android do
  desc "Build a Flutter apk1"
  lane :buildDebug do
    gradle(task: "assemble", project_dir: 'android/')
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?